# Adding values of column to another column

Tags: c#, sql

I had one column which named as `hours` in `sql` so when I entered the values in it through c# visual studio so I need `total hours` which I need to display in the windows form.

```
 private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime date1;
        DateTime date2;
        if (DateTime.TryParse(textBox7.Text, out date1) && DateTime.TryParse(textBox8.Text, out date2))
            textBox6.Text = (date2 - date1).ToString();
        else
            textBox6.Text = "Invalid format";
    }
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please try to add more details.

Comment: Can you post what have you done so far..

Comment: Where is the sql in your code? code is not relevant to the question you posted.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Sqlconnection con=new SqlConnection(strcon);
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand("SELECT SUM(column_name)as TotalHours FROM   table_name",con);
SqlDataReader dr=cmd.ExecuteReader();
while(dr.Read())
{
Label1.Text = dr[0].toString();
}
}
```

Comment: I need to display on the windows form